# Update if exists, else do nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update a value of a model if and only if the model exists. If it doesn't, I do nothing. Searching only seems to return update or create questions/answers, but I do not want to create.

I know I can do it with a simple:

```
found = Model.find_by_id(id)
if found
  update stuff
end
```

However, I feel like there is a way to do this in one call, without assigning any temporary local values or doing an if.

How would I write a rails call to update a record without noisy errors if it doesnt exist?

Latest Rails 3.x

Comment: When you say iff the model exists, do you mean you want to determine  if the app defines a model or if you have some data particular data in the database already?

Comment: If I have some particular data in the db already.

Comment: E.g.: I have a record of customer_help_visits if a customer has visited the help page. When the customer visits the *main* page, their customer_help_visits updates last_browsed. Not all customers have customer_help_visits. 

This is not my actual structure, I realize how silly this architecture seems -- it's just what I can think of as an example without talking specifically about my actual code :]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method of Rails before calling update_attributes on result of `find_by_id` or `where`.

`try` will return `nil` silently without raising exception if the record does not exist. If the record exists, it will update it.

```
found = Model.find_by_id(id).try(:update_attributes, {key: value})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use first_or_initialize combined with new_record? as following:

```
client = Client.where(first_name: 'Nick').first_or_initialize(locked: false)
client.save unless client.new_record?
```

Comment: I *don't* want to create if it doesn't exist.

Comment: that's exactly what `unless new_record?` does

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model is called 'Event' and you search by id, you could do:

```
e = Event.where(:id => id)
if !e.empty?
  e.first.value = new_value
  e.first.save!
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I am wondering if there is a rails command a la update_attributes_if_exists.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, this is probably the simplest solution I found:

```
# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.find_or_initialize_by(fbid: user_params[:fbid])
  @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

If the user with FBID exists, then the record will be updated; otherwise, a new one will be created. You can update the record to match whatever column you want to keep unique. Probably indexing the column would help the search & retrieval etc.

Hope this helps!